# I'm try to add subscription with graphql but it is throwing an error "Not Authorized to access onCreateMessage on type Subscription"

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, graphql, amazon-cognito, aws-amplify

I'm building a simple chat app with aws amplify but when I tried to add graphql subscribe to onMessageCreate it is throwing an error "Not Authorized to access onCreateMessage on type Subscription", I have added auth rule {allow: private}

type Message @model @auth(rules: [{ allow: private, provider: userPools }]) {
id: ID!
owner: String!
message: String!
}

Comment: Are you logged in with an Cognito User?

Comment: Do you still have this problem?